# Least Upper Bounds Of Bounded Functions

Tags: calculus

Is there a bounded function having no least upper or lower bound?If no then how to prove that Bounded functions have both least upper and least lower bound??

Comment: There is no such bounded function. Once a function has a bound, then there is an least upper bound. The lease upper bound is the smallest such bound

Comment: Then how to prove that Bounded functions have least upper and least lower bound?

Comment: As I told you, once you show that a function is bounded then it has lease upper bound.

Comment: The existence of least upper bound is a consequence of construction of real numbers. Check Dedekind’s construction of real numbers for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem. A bounded function has least upper bound.

**Proof.**

Suppose that, for a function $f$, $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$ in the domain of function $f$.

Then by definition , lease upper bound $L$ is $$L=\inf\{\ell\in \mathbb{R}^+: |f(x)|\leq \ell \hspace{1cm}\forall x\}$$

Since the set in the above notation is not empty, for example, $M$ is in there, so $L$ exists.